# Connecting LDAP server in Linux to apache directory studio in windows

Tags: linux, windows, ldap

How to connect LDAP server hosted in Linux to apache directory studio in windows?

Comment: Just configure a connection to the IP address of the ldap server - you probably need a port (369 if over ldap, 636 if over ldaps; but it defaults to those ports if you use `ldap(s)://1.2.3.4/`). This is stuff that's documented on the directory studio website, though, so you probably want to [read the documentation on the website](https://directory.apache.org/studio/)

Comment: @Petesh The default LDAP port is 389.

Comment: Oh well, that's one typo I can't correct.